# Error - 'English' object has no attribute 'add_label'

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I have trained on spacy's blank model with 5 entities and now I have made a new data with 2 new entities. On training on top of old model with 5 entities,

```
nlp.add_label(LABEL)
```

gives error:

AttributeError: 'English' object has no attribute 'add_label'

Spacy version : 2.1.4
Python : 3.6

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `add_label` on the pipeline component (e.g. `ner` or `textcat`) - not on the `nlp` object. It's probably useful to read through the documentation in a bit more detail [here](https://spacy.io/usage/training).

Comment: Then I get this error "Could not find a transition with the name 'U-B-PAPER' in the NER model."